# Gettext from android button return ""

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm trying to create a multiple choice quiz using 4 buttons with array. i couldn't get the variable from the button text

my button `text: buttonA: Obama, buttonB: Lincoln, buttonC: Washington, buttonD: Bush`
the correct answer is Obama `(buttonA)`

when i change the code on the answer line into `answer = "Obama";` (comment line), it works. But when i change into a `gettext()` from the `buttonA text`, it didn't works.

i checked the answer variable from `gettext()`, it returns ""

Please advise, thank you

here's the code

```
package com.trivia;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuWho extends Activity {
    private String keyanswer ,answer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutwho);


        Button buttons[] = new Button[4];
        buttons[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        buttons[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        buttons[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
        buttons[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonD);

        keyanswer = "Obama";
        answer = "";
    }

    public void cekanswer (View view) {

        Button selectedbutton = (Button) view;
           switch (selectedbutton.getId())
           {
              case R.id.buttonA:
                  //answer = "Obama";
                  answer = selectedbutton.getText().toString();
                  break;

              case R.id.buttonB:
                  answer = (String) selectedbutton.getText();
                  break;

              case R.id.buttonC:
                  answer = (String) selectedbutton.getText();
                  break;

              case R.id.buttonD:
                  answer = (String) selectedbutton.getText();
                  break;
           }

           //cek answer
        if (answer == keyanswer)
                {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Correct !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Wrong !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
}

}
```

Comment: Nobody answered your question. I'm having the same issue with getText(). It just returns an empty string "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `answer.equals(keyanswer)`.  `Equals` checks the data of the `strings`, `==` only checks if the references are the same.

Answer (score 1):

With Strings in Java, using `==` only looks to see if the references are the same. You must use the method `.equals()` to see if the actual data of the strings is the same.

Here is another SO post on the subject
[.equals() vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

And the Java documentation..

[String#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

So for your answer specifically, change the line `if (answer == keyanswer)` to `if (answer.equals(keyanswer)){//do work}`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (answer == keyanswer)
```

this is the wrong programming to compare two string. You need to use this one

```
if (answer.equals(keyanswer))
```

or

```
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(keyanswer))
```